# Report with two subreports getting duplicated records

Tags: ms-access

I'm trying to make report with two sub reports, but i get duplicated records. In sub reports I'm using one field from main report for query criteria, and if there is 4 record in my table i get 4x sub report. I tried with group & sort, but it didn't work. any idea?

thanks

Comment: if anyone hawe some idea i can send u .accdb to see problem

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if you have your sub reports in the detail section. If so, move them inside a group (unique id field) header and then minimize the detail section to a zero height.

Essentially, the subreports repeat for each of the four records in main report as any item in detail section is designed to do. But placing them in a group section will appear once for a distinct value.